# Why are the limits of integration functions of y, and not x

Tags: multiple-integral

When solving problems on multiple integration, why are the limits of integration functions of y, if integrating with respect to x. 
Please can you explain it graphically?

**Edit**:

In single variable integration, the limits of integration a and b are typically along the axis of the variable of integration which is x in this case
$$\int_a^b f(x) \,dx$$

But in multiple integration, we have
$$\int_{h_1(y)}^{h_2(y)} f_x(x, y) \,dx= f(x, y) \bigg\rvert_{h_1(y)}^{h_2(y)} = f(h_2(y), y) - f(h_1(y), y)$$ with respect to x, **and**

$$\int_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)} f_y(x, y) \,dy= f(x, y) \bigg\rvert_{g_1(x)}^{g_2(x)} = f(x, g_2(x)) - f(x, g_1(x))$$ with respect to y

- from Larson Edwards Calculus, section 14.1

So when integrating with respect to x, why were the limits of integration expressed as functions of y?

Comment: Try thinking about the case of a single variable.

Comment: It might help (or maybe not) to know that in your example $x$ is a dummy variable. In particular, your example could potentially be written as $\displaystyle \int\limits_{0}^yf$. How are you going to word your questions then?

Comment: For two variables, the domain of integration is a subset of the (x,y) plane.  Unless the boundary  is a rectangle with sides parallel to the axes, it will be necessarily described by some functional relationship between x and y.

Comment: It does not have to be (I guess). See this book on page 758 Chapter 14 Examples 1 and 2.https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=4m0PmSJyWtYC&pg=PA758&dq=visualize+%22multiple+integrals%22+bounded&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjCt62tkv_cAhUIbFAKHUaFB-g4ChDoAQg9MAQ#v=onepage&q=visualize%20%22multiple%20integrals%22%20bounded&f=false

Comment: Thank you for the response. I edited the question, because it wasn't clear initially